# Effective index for mongodb collection

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing

We have next collection with objects (like this):

```
{
  "a": unix timestamp,
  "b" : string,
  "c": usefull data ..
}
```

And have request to find how much elements are in next query:

```
(a >= t1 && a <= t2) && (b in [b1, b2, b3, ..., bN]
```

N could be more then 1K, b(i) all different strings (IDs)

What index will be more effective?

Comment: How much records will there typically be between t1 and t2. And how many records in total?

Comment: a good sample JSON document will help to identify the best query route(for testing)

Answer (score 0):

db.collname.createIndex({a:1, b :1 })